# pthread_setschedparam not working on GCC with mingw64

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, pthreads, mingw-w64

I'm trying to run the example code from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle) on Windows 11 with GCC v13.2.0 installed (MSYS2, UCRT runtime):

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>

std::mutex iomutex;
void f(int num)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    sched_param sch;
    int policy;
    pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &sch);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(iomutex);
    std::cout << "Thread " << num << " is executing at priority " << sch.sched_priority << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f, 1), t2(f, 2);

    sched_param sch;
    int policy;
    pthread_getschedparam(t1.native_handle(), &policy, &sch);
    sch.sched_priority = 20;
    int result = pthread_setschedparam(t1.native_handle(), SCHED_FIFO, &sch);
    if (result)
        std::cout << "Failed to setschedparam: " << std::strerror(result) << '\n';

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

The code compiles, but the output is:

```
Failed to setschedparam: not supported
Thread 2 is executing at priority 0
Thread 1 is executing at priority 0
```

This happens even when running as administrator. Contrast this with running the same code on Ubuntu, which outputs (only when using sudo):

```
Thread 1 is executing at priority 20
Thread 2 is executing at priority 0
```

I used `g++ -v` and verified that GCC is configured with `--enable-threads=posix` and explicitly says "Thread model: posix". Why does this code not work? Is it a bug in winpthread, or does setting priorities work differently on Windows even if pthreads are used?

Update: I modified the code above to print out the error based on the return value of `pthread_setschedparam`, as recommended by "n. m. could be an AI" in the comments.

Comment: This function doesn't set errno, it *returns* an error code, so try using `strerror` on the return value.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This code is from cppreference.com, so I guess they made a mistake. If I print out the returned error code, I get 129, but I have no idea what that means. `std::strerror` on that error number simply says "not supported". Please let me know if you can think of a solution to my problem.

Comment: 129 on MinGW is the error code ENOTSUP, "not supported". [See the source](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/mingw/+/56ddde351b6dc8558e0a6b08636e9af2dca3d5fd/mingw-w64-v4.0.4/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/src/sched.c#139). It looks like the policy parameter must be SCHED_OTHER and nothing else, other policies, although valid, are not supported.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, if I change `SCHED_FIFO` to `SCHED_OTHER`, it still doesn't work, this time with the error being 22: "invalid argument".

Comment: Look at the source again. The priority should be between -15 and 15.

Comment: You're right! When I change it to that value, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, based on the comments by [n. m. could be an AI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m-could-be-an-ai).

First of all, mingw64 appears to only support `SCHED_OTHER` for the scheduling policy. Second, even though on Linux the maximum thread priority is 99, on Windows it is 15. This can be obtained by running `sched_get_priority_max(policy)`, which returns 15. (Alternatively, if we include `windows.h`, it defines `THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL` as 15, and that macro can be used directly with `pthread_setschedparam`.)

Here is a corrected version of the code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>

std::mutex iomutex;
void f(int num)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    sched_param sch;
    int policy;
    pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &sch);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(iomutex);
    std::cout << "Thread " << num << " is executing at priority " << sch.sched_priority << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f, 1), t2(f, 2);

    sched_param sch;
    int policy;
    pthread_getschedparam(t1.native_handle(), &policy, &sch);
    int max_priority = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
    std::cout << "The maximum thread priority on this system is: " << max_priority << '\n';
    sch.sched_priority = max_priority;
    int result = pthread_setschedparam(t1.native_handle(), SCHED_OTHER, &sch);
    if (result)
        std::cout << "Failed to setschedparam: " << std::strerror(result) << '\n';

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```